# Obsolete RetryPolicy code for Azure blob storage

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, http-status-codes, blobstorage, operationcontext, retrypolicy

I am coding an MVC5 application, and am uploading `BlockBlobs` to `Azure`.

I have some Microsoft code that is now obsolete, and I wish to convert this obsolete code to code that will work in my application.

Here is the old code:

```
BlockBlob.PutBlock(blockId, chunkStream, null, null, new BlobRequestOptions() { RetryPolicy = RetryPolicies.Retry(3, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)) });
```

I have code that does work, however this code does not use a `RetryPolicy`.

Here is the code with no `RetryPolicy`:

```
BlockBlob.PutBlock(blockId, chunkStream, null, null, null, null);
```

Can I please have some help to construct the `BlobRequestOptions` object correctly that uses a `RetryPolicy`?

Here is what I have so far:

```
BlobRequestOptions blobRequestOptions = new BlobRequestOptions();
blobRequestOptions.RetryPolicy.CreateInstance();
TimeSpan timeSpan = new TimeSpan();
TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
blobRequestOptions.RetryPolicy.ShouldRetry(3, 0, new Exception(), out timeSpan, new OperationContext());
```

I am not sure of the following:

1. What status code to use.
2. What to use for the LastException.
3. The out value for the timespan.
4. What to use for OperationContext.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient is deprecated, you now need to use Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage or more specifically the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.RetryPolicies.

For that retry, this should work

```
new BlobRequestOptions() { RetryPolicy = new LinearRetry(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), 3) }
```